# UWP Underline Textblock with ImageBrush as Foreground does not show the Underline

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10, textblock, underline

I am using an `ImageBrush` as a`Textblock` `Foreground`. It works fine but when the `Textblock` is `Underline`, the line does not show.

To reproduce. In XAML

```
<TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" FontSize="80" FontWeight="Bold">
    <Underline>This is my text</Underline>
</TextBlock>
```

In code behind

```
Uri uri = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/0.png");
BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage(uri);
ImageBrush imageBrush = new ImageBrush();
imageBrush.ImageSource = bmp;
this.textBlock.Foreground = imageBrush;
```

Here's how it looks like with a SolidColorBrush with underline applied

[image]

Then when the `ImageBrush` is applied, the underline is gone

[image]

So my question is how do I apply `ImageBrush` `Foreground` to an `Underline` `Textblock` in UWP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So my question is how do I apply ImageBrush Foreground to an Underline Textblock in UWP?

By default, the underline will be removed when the `ImageBrush` has been applied to `TextBlock`'s `Foreground` property.

The workaround is using [`Border`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.border) to simulate the underline:

```
<Border BorderThickness="0, 0, 0, 2" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=textBlock}" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=textBlock}">
            <Border.BorderBrush>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="Assets/0.jpg" />
            </Border.BorderBrush>
            <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" FontSize="50" FontWeight="Bold">
                <TextBlock.Foreground>
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="Assets/0.jpg" />
                </TextBlock.Foreground>
                <Underline><Run Text="This is my text"/></Underline>
            </TextBlock>
        </Border>
```

[image]

You can create a UserControl/CustomControl to maintain reusability.

Comment: Note that this isn't a true underline and does not respect the glyph heights and offsets. This is visible in your preview where the underline is pushed to below the lowest point in the 'y', rather than intersecting with its descender.

Answer (score 0):

You can make inline text with wrappanel like this
[Inline Texts Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GNiWR.png)